# DirectShow data copy is TOO slow

Tags: c, performance, memory, directshow, screen-capture

Have USB 3.0 HDMI Capture device. It uses YUY2 format (2 bytes per pixel) and 1920x1080 resolution.

Video capture Output Pin connects directly to Video Render input Pin.
And all works good. It shows me 1920x1080 without any freezes.
But I need to make screenshot every second. So this is what I do:

```
void CaptureInterface::ScreenShoot() {

    IMemInputPin* p_MemoryInputPin = nullptr;
    hr = p_RenderInputPin->QueryInterface(IID_IMemInputPin, (void**)&p_MemoryInputPin);
    IMemAllocator* p_MemoryAllocator = nullptr;
    hr = p_MemoryInputPin->GetAllocator(&p_MemoryAllocator);

    IMediaSample* p_MediaSample = nullptr;
    hr = p_MemoryAllocator->GetBuffer(&p_MediaSample, 0, 0, 0);

    long buff_size = p_MediaSample->GetSize(); //buff_size = 4147200 Bytes
    BYTE* buff = nullptr;
    hr = p_MediaSample->GetPointer(&buff);

    //BYTE CaptureInterface::ScreenBuff[1920*1080*2]; defined in header

    //--------- TOO SLOW (1.5 seconds for 4 MBytes) ----------
    std::memcpy(ScreenBuff, buff, buff_size);
    //--------------------------------------------

    p_MediaSample->Release();
    p_MemoryAllocator->Release();
    p_MemoryInputPin->Release();

    return;
}
```

Any other operations with this buffer is very slow too.

But If I use `memcpy` on other data (2 arrays in my class for example same size 4MB) It is very fast. <0.01sec

Comment: Feelings like this memory pages is just a link to phisical buffer on capture device. On other side of USB 3.0 wire. And memcpy each time to copy portion of data inits USB connection and then close it.

Comment: If you tried inserting a tee filter before the renderer? You can then try to dump the video data from the second pin.

Comment: Thank for All. I had enumerate filters in my graph and see that capturepraphbuilder2 add 2 filters themself. Smart Tee and AVI Decompressor. Some strange that AVI Decompessor do nothing. input and output formats are the same (yuy2). But I find first pin of it, get buffer and it was not in videomemory, so I manualy decompress yuy2 to RGB32 very fast (<0.01s) by predefined LUT table.

Answer (score 0):

Video memory is (might be) slow to read back by its nature (e.g. [VMR9 IBasicVideo->GetCurrentImage very slow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/d986d024-1cfd-48d6-9142-d74b205ec78c/vmr9-ibasicvideogetcurrentimage-very-slow?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) and you can find other references). You normally want to grab the data before it actually reaches video memory.

Additionally, the way you read data is not quite reliable. You don't know what frame you are actually copying and it might so happen that you even read blackness or garbage, or vice versa your acquiring access to buffer freezes the main video streaming. This is because you are grabbing an unused buffer from pool of available buffers rather than a buffer that corresponds to specific video frame. Your getting an image from such buffer happen in a fragile assumption that unused data from previously streamed frame was initialized and is not yet overwritten by anything else.

Comment: Video memory is fast to be written to and slow to be read back from [to system memory].

Comment: Nature of videomemory? You mean that memory phisical on my videocard and there is many problems to copy from it? Now it works fine. I grab data from monitor1 and show it on monitor2. Now delay is about <0.1sec. But if I add any other filter delay becomes >0.5sec. I just need one frame per second to analize it.(may be asynchronously) All other 59 frames should be displayed as fast as they can. (<0.1sec delay)

Comment: Think it writes from usb direct to videomemory.

Comment: Seems only way is write own filter :(

Comment: Or alternatively you might want to try a `memcpy` alternative copy from this article: [Copying Accelerated Video Decode Frame Buffers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/copying-accelerated-video-decode-frame-buffers). If my memory serves me right there are some copy implementations in VirtualDub source code as well.